# Creating responsive element in XAML

Tags: xaml, responsive-design, uwp, responsive

I am absolutely new in UWP and its responsive design, so I need help.
Where's the problem?

e.g. I need 4 responsive buttons on landing page, but in each view it looks quite the same. So the button doesn't change, but looks same on desktop, and same on the phone emulator (or when I change screen resolution). For better description, there are some screens:

Buttons on large 23" screen - looks good, but...
[image: Buttons on large 23" screen]

..buttons on small 5" screen (portrait) - buttons are larger then canvas...
[image: buttons on small 5" screen (portrait)]

So my question is: How to make buttons responsive?

Here is my sourcecode:

```
<Page
    x:Class="STCApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:STCApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="83*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="998*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="83" Width="480" Background="#33DCFF00"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="83" Width="480" Grid.Column="1" Background="#33FF0000"/>
        <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="83" Width="480" Grid.Column="2" Background="#3300FF0C"/>
        <Button x:Name="button_Copy2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="83" Width="480" Grid.Column="3" Background="#330080FF"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For responsive design, we'd better avoid using fixed width and height. We can remove `Width` and `Height` setting in `Button` and set it's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` like following to make the button responsive.

```
<Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#33DCFF00" Content="Button" />
```

In this scenario, each button will occupy a cell in the grid and their width and height will change automatically according to the size of the gird. Following is a complete sample and for more info about the layout design, please see [**Layout for UWP apps**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/index).

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="83*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="998*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#33DCFF00" Content="Button" />
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#33FF0000" Content="Button" />
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#3300FF0C" Content="Button" />
    <Button x:Name="button_Copy2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#330080FF" Content="Button" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's better for you to use a `RelativePanel` which you can handle with Visual States that will change according to the available screen size. This might help

[Windows 10 RelativePanel Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Relative-Panel-for-a-aff79319)